# Getting mydomain.com/subdomain to resolve to subdomain.mydomain.com

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, redirect, subdomain, permalinks

I have content on subdomain1.mydomain.com which can't reside on mydomain.com/subdomain1.  Nevertheless, all my other content resides in folders of the mydomain.com/subdomain* type.

For the sake of consistency, I'd like the content actually located at subdomain1.mydomain.com to appear as if it were on mydomain.com/subdomain1 — Is there any way, using .htaccess, that I can achieve this, bearing in mind that:

(1) the subdomain itself also has a nested permalink structure, meaning that there are additional folders in the directory structure of the subdomain;

(2) I want the browser to display the address as mydomain/subdomain1 after the redirect.

Comment: Because of the reference to .htaccess, I assumed it is Apache and I retagged accordingly.

Comment: The question is far too vague: is it static files on the disk or some sort of CMS and, if so, which one?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this has a DNS tag. DNS will not do what you want.
DNS is designed to resolve host name to an ip address (`A` record) and vice versa (`PTR` record). It can also point one hostname to another hostname, and this is called a `CNAME` record.

As far as redirecting subdomain1.domain.com to domain.com/subdomain1

try something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond    %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1\.
RewriteRule    /(.*) http://www.domain.com/subdomain1/$1 [R=301,L]
```